# xslt: check if a variable is not blank

Tags: validation, xslt

The code below validate an input (for i.e 12012016 as 12.01.2016),

```
<xsl:template name="handleDate">    
  <xsl:param name="input"/>   
  <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 9, 2)" />
  <xsl:text>.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 6, 2)" />
  <xsl:text>.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 1, 4)" />
</xsl:template>
```

but whenever a date is blank (not filled), as a result I got only 2 dots(..) in the output, and when I try to import it in other system I got an error, because (..) is not a valid date.
I tried this, but still doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template name="handleDate">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="input!= ''">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 9, 2)" />
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 6, 2)" />
      <xsl:text>.</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 1, 4)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select=" '' " />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>             

<xsl:call-template name="handleDate">
  <xsl:with-param name="input" select="Field[@guid='123']/@xmlConvertedValue" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Input is for i.e:

> name;date;name2

and the output should be like:

> test1;;test2 (if date is blank)

Comment: In your `test` expression, you forgot the $ symbol: `<xsl:when test="input!= ''">` -- so `input` is evaluated as an element name instead of as a variable or parameter.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi: Could you put that in an answer, so the question list doesn't keep showing this question as unanswered?

Answer (score 2):

In your `test` expression, you forgot the `$` prefix for variable and parameter names:

```xml
<xsl:when test="input!= ''">
```

As a result, `input` here is evaluated as an element name instead of the name of a variable or parameter.  What you need instead is:

```xml
<xsl:when test="$input!= ''">
```

Try that and let us know how it goes.